# User rank algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I would like to implement a kind of user rank system in my forum. 
I have 7 ranks, 1-7.

I have four parameters on which the users should be judged (weighing in parentheses):
Number of likes on their comments (50%)
Amount of comments written (30%)
Average length of comments (15%)
Threads created (5%)

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this in PHP? Any other comments on the ranking system is also welcomed

Comment: You might want to watch this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9097919/338803

Comment: Seems like simple enough math... get the individual score components, add/weigh them, done.

Answer (score 0):

Its straight forward, what you are creating is a weight score per user.  I would calculate it with a cronjob, and keep a static weight for each user in their profile/user table.

It is really an open ended question, as you can do whatever you like, calculate on the fly, schedule it, etc;